# How pass dynamic value to a INDEX function in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to write a dynamic excel condition to fetch some values based on the cell Contents.

My excel sheet contain `3` tabs. `Home`, `tab_1` and `tab_2` respectively. In the `home` tab, I have some text contents for selecting `sheet` and `table`.

[image]

In the `tab_1` sheet, i have tables named as `Table_1`, `Table_2`,`Table_3` and `Table_4`.

[image]

Now I want to get some elements from the table based on the text values.

**Example:** if the sheet name = `Tab_1` and Table name = `Table_1` then i will take the `2nd index` values from `Table_1` array in `Tab_1` sheet.
My plan is to do dynamically using excel formula.

So i have tried to write the below logic to get 2nd index values.

```
INDEX(INDIRECT("'"&$B$2& "'!B1:F1"),2)
```

here it will take `$B2` as Tab_1 . I am passing table value as `"B1:F1"`.

Now i don't know how to get the matching array (instead of `B1:F1`) with the cell `$B3` in the home sheet (Table_1).

Any suggestion or help ?

Comment: Have you considered just naming your tables and then using the Table names? This would greatly simplify the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after some research, I found the solution. We can use MATCH function to check the exact row name.

`INDIRECT("'"&$B$2&"'!A1:F4)`

This will search in the next tab (cell B2 text name ie: `Tab_1` and table from `A1` to `F4` cells)

`MATCH($B2,INDIRECT("'"&$B$2&"'!A1:F4),0)`

This will search the exact name (from cell `B3` text ie: `Table_1`) from the tab

So All together you can write below function:

```
INDEX(INDIRECT("'"&$B$2&"'!A1:F4),MATCH($B3,INDIRECT("'"&$B$2&"'!A1:F4),0),2)
```

I hope this solution will help you someone who facing for this kind of problems.